Is it possible to query, alter, and update data in EF Core during a migration up and also to reverse that in migration down?
We want to modify a table in our database by adding a column and then updating all of the records in that table. For simplification, we are adding ValueB as the new column:



ID
ValueA
ValueB (new column)




1
0583
100


2
0381
200




Step 1: Add the new column (straight forward in EF)
Step 2: Get the rows
Step 3: Using ValueA feed it into some blackbox C# method which returns a new ValueA and an additional ValueB.
Step 4: Update the rows with the new ValueA and ValueB.

I am not sure simply using the Sql method will suffice, and there isn't really a way to avoid using the C# method. We literally have to update the records by feeding the original ValueA into the method to get the new ValueA and ValueB.

Simpler approach could be separating logic from migration. Do first migration to add columns ValueATemp, ValueB, then populate those outside of migration. Only after checking data was correctly inserted/updated would I do a simple ValueATemp => ValueA update. Now the ValueATemp column can be dropped anytime on subsequent migrations without fear of losing or corrupting data.

In EF Core migrations there is no way to open connection to database. Migrations just generate SQL. So, if it possible, use Sql method.
